# Suppess UIView re-layout when child view changes

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

See UPDATE below:

I am confused about UIView layout as subviews are moving. I have a "Surface" UIView with several "Item" subviews on it. The user is allowed to click on the items and drag them around the surface.

What I have noticed though is that whenever a Surface's Item subview moves (is dragged by the user), the Surface is marked as needing to be relayed out.

I do not want the Surface to layout the Items after the user moved them. That is pretty much the whole point, I am allowing the user to position them as they see fit. However, there are times, initial creation is a prime example, where I do need the Surface to place the items.

So I would like one of two things:

A) Suppress SetNeedsLayout() calls on the surface when one of its Item subviews changes (moves).

--OR --

B) Know why I was asked to relayout, and if it was caused by Item motion then do nothing.

I cannot imagine I am the first to have this question.... :)

###### UPDATE:

After more investigation, I discovered more about what is going on. It is not that moving the Surface's items causes a Surface relayout, as I originally thought. It was only the initiation of a drag which caused the relayout. In digging further I discovered that it wasn't even the drag that was the cause, but a call to the Surface's bringSubviewToFront.

I need to bring the Item to the front, so that when it is dragged it appears on top of the others.

I can understand why bringing a subview might trigger a relayout, but again it is not what I want to happen.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `setNeedsLayout:` in your Surface class?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should override layoutSubviews in your Surface UIView.

Comment: I am. The problem is that when it is invoked I am not sure *why*. Whether I really want to do a relayout depends on whether it was caused by the subview moving or not.

A hacky workaround is to remember what the Surface's Frame was the last time I layed out, and if it hasn't changed, then don't bother. This is not elegant, and moreover not necessarily correct. It really has to do with the cause of the relayout request.